# Using apache thrift with typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, thrift

I generated .js and .d.ts files with the apache thrift compiler. How can I use this files in my existing Angular2/Typescript-Project?
I tried to use

```
///<reference path="./thrift.d.ts"/>
///<reference path="./Service.d.ts"/>
```

And

```
import Thrift = require("./thrift");
import Service = require("./Service")
```

If i use this four lines, the typescript compiler is not complaining, but "Thrift" is not defined when i want to use it. thrift.js, Service.js and both .d.ts files are existing in the folder.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually reference your thrift.js in the index.html

Answer (score 0):

yarn add @types/thrift

```
import * as thrift from  'thrift';
...
var transport = thrift.TBufferedTransport;
var protocol = thrift.TBinaryProtocol;
```