# Error: Cannot find name 'Thrift' when using Thrift with Typescript

Tags: typescript, thrift, typescript-typings

I wanted to use Thrift with Typescript for my Nodejs project
Here is the error that I am running into

```
src/gen-js/myService.d.ts:9:12 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Thrift'.

10     input: Thrift.TJSONProtocol;
              ~~~~~~
src/gen-js/myService.d.ts:10:1 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Thrift'.

11     output: Thrift.TJSONProtocol;
               ~~~~~~
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Thrift'.

...(more of the same)

src/gen-js/myService_types.d.ts:198:32 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Thrift'.

198   class StoreException extends Thrift.TException {
                               ~~~~~~
...(more of the same)
```

I have installed the `@types/thrift` and also setup my tsconfig.json as follows

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/types/*"]
    },
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "esnext"
    ]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Seems fine right? and still running into the error. Any idea how to successfully build this?

P.S. I am using Typescript 3.2, Thrift v0.11 and @types/thrift 0.10.7

Answer (score 0):

After installing the types you still need to import them before referencing them.

Edit:

After looking at the type definitions it isn't.. ideally typed. If using the wildcard import type (second example) there is also a nested `Thrift` namespace

```
import { Thrift, TJSONProtocol } from 'thrift';

const protocol: TJSONProtocol = // instance;

class StoreException extends Thrift.TException {}
```

or

```
import * as Thrift from 'thrift';

const protocol: Thrift.TJSONProtocol = // instance;

class StoreException extends Thrift.Thrift.TException {}
```

Comment: I agree, the typings are not ideal at all. Another error thrown by vscode is [2306]  which means that `myService.d.ts is not a module`. Also I did forget to mention that the errors are being thrown in the generated files. I'll edit it right now.

Comment: @Ashniu123, make sure you've imported the `thrift` module in your `.ts` file, clean the build directory and build again. I just set up a quick test-project and it compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: I created a simple gist here, please explain what is wrong
https://gist.github.com/Ashniu123/c73f81b0151c27289779a8a632cbc631

Comment: @Ashniu123, from what I understand now you're getting a completely different error from the original one. Which is it then?

Comment: The error is still the same, the thrift file I am using is too long (200+ lines) so I made a shorter version of it with minimum service functions. But if you could solve even the `ping()` issue I'd be grateful. The error I am aiming at is `error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Thrift'.` in the generated `gen-js` folder. It shouldn't be coming right? Could it be the Typescript version issue? I am using 3.2 whereas I think the generated file adheres more to 2.3.

Comment: Does the generated file have an `import` of the Thrift module in the beginning?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. What library are you using to generate those files?

Comment: @Ashniu123, then you need to dive into what the generator is doing. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42715829/using-apache-thrift-with-typescript) could also help, I think

Comment: I saw that answer and it didn't seem helpful. Nevermind, thanks for the answer. I'd rather switch back to JS and wait for the new `node-ts` coming out in Thrift v0.12.